# Replace with multiple value in string - Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

Question :

```
var str = "I have a <animal>, a <flower>, and a <car>.";
```

now the above string I want to replace below with Tiger, Rose and BMW

```
<animal> , <flower> and <car>
```

Please suggest the best approach for this.

I am working on Angular 2 Application with Typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @JoeClay normal string is ok .. but i am facing issue for <animal> or <car> or <flower> string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with a replacer function to evaluate each match and return the appropriate replacement.

```
var str = "I have a <animal>, a <flower>, and a <car>.";

function replace(source : string, replacements : { [name:string]: string }) {
    return str.replace(  new RegExp("<([A-z]*)>", "g"), (m) => {
        return replacements[m.substring(1, m.length -1)];
    });
}

console.log(replace(str, {
    "animal" : "Tiger",
    "flower" : "Rose",
    "car" : "BMW"
}))
```

Comment: Or less verbose, the function body could just be: `return str.replace(/<([A-z]*)>/g, m => replacements[m.substring(1, m.length - 1)]);`

Comment: @Duncan you are right shorter that way, but since it was a longish expression I though it looked better in a multiline

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript you should declare your string according to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html with `let str = 'I have a <animal>, a <flower>, and a <car>.';` Note the single quotes which is a recommendation of the Angular Styleguide (enforced e.g. with *ng lint* in a continuous delivery pipeline).

Instead of replacing with the common javascript replace methods you can substitute the placeholder already in the code:

[Screenshot code see the backticks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW34w.png)